# one query per user login on rails possible?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, model, controller

So obviously when users login, the controller pulls the user's information from the database.  Throughout the users session, loading certain pages such as their profile/settings/posts requires database queries every time he or she wants to view them (through the user instance variable for each controller action) the way I have my application setup.

My question is, is there a way to query all of this information once for all of the views/controllers to access globally, so that when the user goes to view their information it doesn't have to be queried every time and put more load on the database?

Long story short, I'm worried about the scalability of my application and any suggestions here would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> loading certain pages such as their profile/settings/posts requires database queries every time he or she wants to view them

Yes, this is obvious. Every time he requests which will be treated separately by web server

> is there a way to query all of this information once for all of the views/controllers to access globally

Basically, we can, but this is not a good practice, to improve performance you can:

- [Eager loading](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/) to avoid N+1 queries
- [Caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html)
- Double check in codebase to remove redundant code, redundant queries
- Detecting heavy task, considering put it to background
- Integrate [Profiler Gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/rack-mini-profiler) to recognize & fix performance issue

Answer (score 1):

> information once for all of the views/controllers to access globally

This is "cloud computing" and doesn't exist right now, regardless of what those in Redmond or Redwood Shores tell you.

Rails is built on the [HTTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), which is [*stateless*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) -- each time your request is served, the server "forgets" you ever existed.

What you're asking is basically how a *stateful* application works, which we don't have in the current setup. A good example of stateful is `ssh` or `ftp`.

---

Unfortunately, in the scope of a Rails application, there is no simple way to achieve what you want.

Each time you send a request, client-side [*session*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions) data is processed to build out data objects such as `current_user`, `posts` etc. Unless you invoke multiple instances of the application (for each user), you'd have to create some sort of perpetual data store for all the records (caching).

There *are* workarounds:

- ["In-memory"](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/features/database-in-memory-option/index.html) databases
- Storing "generic" data in a cache & scoping around stateful data
- Optimizing your DB queries (to combat `n+1` etc)

--

I can explain each if you want, I don't like huge posts but it may give you some ideas. If you comment, I'll write an update if required.